# Xiaomi /Mi GetApps old apk version of my app not showing update option in google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle, xiaomi

I have uploaded **aab(app bundle)** on google playstore with versioncode-40 and Mi getApps (Mi app store) have older version(version-30) of same **app (apk)** .still im not getting update option in google playstore.

Case :I have installed app from Mi app store(GetApps) which has older version and i opened the google playstore ,i'm getting only "open" and "uninstall" but not "update" option

Please Help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar issue, Here is a response from Mi Support team.

"***We feel regretful to inform you that Getapps currently don't support updating applications in this way.***"

[Screen shot of response from Mi dev team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slzC7.png)